# Salesforce Send with Docusign button

Tags: salesforce, docusignapi

I have a custom button that works 90% of the time. When it doesn't work I get this error message, "Unable to display this envelope either because the user has insufficient access or the envelope does not exist." I'm not sure what the issue with my button is. I've tried using JSENCODE before my fields, I thought it might have been a character within the address or name that was causing the error but it is still not working. Here is my code below:

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/apex/dsfs__DocuSign_JavaScript")} 
DocuSign_CreateEnvelope(); 

//********* Option Declarations *********// 
var 
RC = '', 
RSL = '', 
RSRO = '', 
RROS = '', 
CCRM = '', 
CCTM = '', 
CCNM = '', 
CRCL = '', 
CRL = 'Email~e_vazquez10@yahoo.com;LastName~{!Properties__c.Acquisitions_Analyst_Name__c};Role~Signer 1;RoutingOrder~1', 
OCO = 'Tag', 
DST = '', 
LA = '', 
CEM = 'Hello,\\n\\n Attached is the purchase contract to sign.',
CES = 'Offer for {!Properties__c.Full_Property_Address__c}', 
STB = '0', 
SSB = '1', 
SES = '1', 
SEM = '1', 
SRS = '0', 
SCS = '0', 
RES = '0,1,3,1,7,1'; 

//********* Page Callout (Do not modify) *********// 
window.location.href = 
"/apex/dsfs__DocuSign_CreateEnvelope?DSEID=0&SourceID={!Properties_Document__c.Id}&RC="+RC+"&RSL="+RSL+"&RSRO="+RSRO+"&RROS="+RROS+"&CCRM="+CCRM+"&CCTM="+CCTM+"&CRCL="+CRCL+"&CRL="+CRL+"&OCO="+OCO+"&DST="+DST+"&CCNM="+CCNM+"&LA="+LA+"&CEM="+CEM+"&CES="+CES+"&SRS="+SRS+"&STB="+STB+"&SSB="+SSB+"&SES="+SES+"&SEM="+SEM+"&SRS="+SRS+"&SCS="+SCS+"&RES="+RES;
//*******************************************//
```